# Customize a JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am brand new to JQuery and my Javascript knowledge is limited to only knowing how to work with Mootools. I need to change the behavior of [this carousel](http://labs.juliendecaudin.com/barousel/) so that when you mouseover, it stops rotating.

I need to know if there is a way of doing this without editing the plug in too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#barousel_itemnav').barousel({
        slideDuration: 5000
    });

    $('#barousel_itemnav').hover(function(){
        $(this).barousel({
            slideDuration: 0
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this).barousel({
            slideDuration: 5000
        });
    });
});
```